# What is the opposite word for "torn" in - "page is torn"?

Tags: antonyms

The opposite words listed at [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/torn?s=t) do not seem to be fitting in the context of a page.

The antonyms listed there include:

> *fixed OK unbroken working healed mended perfect*

Comment: Fixed or mended seem like good choices in provided context.

Comment: I think you can use the [idiom in one piece](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+one+piece).

Comment: Depending on the placement of the tear, the book can be *rebound* - past tense of *rebind*.

Comment: The best opposite is **not torn** in "your page is not torn" unless you specify any context where this word would be used.

Answer (score 5):

[**Intact**](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/intact?s=t) seems to be opposite of torn in the context of the page.

Comment: As  does *whole*, but we really don't know what you mean: there is difference between a page that was never torn and a page that has been torn and fixed.

Comment: @GoDucks I really don't understand what kind of context you are talking about.  I used "is" by which I meant that it is present tense. That means that the page is " still " torn.  What context are you talking about?

Comment: I missed that. And I assume I did because (1) lots of times the question in the title is repeated in the body of the question; but (2) mainly because **page is torn** is not grammatical. *Page* is a count noun, so you need a determiner before it: A page is torn, the page is torn, my page is torn, this page is torn. In any event, the most common opposite is *not torn*. *Untorn* is not used as much. And *whole* and *intact* are correct but most people would just say, 'Really, my page is *not torn*'.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you mean by "opposite." The truest antonym for *torn* is probably [*untorn*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/untorn).

But one could make a case for these words, depending on what you were trying to convey:

- [pristine](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pristine?a=british) (new or ​almost new, and in very good ​condition)
- [crisp](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/crisp_1) (crisp cloth or paper is smooth, clean, and fresh)
- [untattered](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/untattered) (not torn or ragged)

Comment: All three adjectives in "A page is pristine", "A page is crisp", "A page is untattered" don't sound more idiomatic than "A page is not compromised" or "A page is unbroken".  Shouldn't this rule be applied? **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**

Comment: @Rathony - That rule is being followed here. The O.P. is asking for an antonym for the word "torn" **in the context of a page**. As for my suggestions, they are not arbitrary: standard book ratings classify [Very Fine condition](http://www.addall.com/Help/glossary.html) as having "crisp pages and tight binding"; a collector's comic book in "[pristine](http://robot6.comicbookresources.com/2014/08/pristine-copy-of-action-comics-1-sells-for-record-3-2-million/)" condition sold for $3.2M; and _tattered_ is a [common adjective](http://www.tatteredbookandcoffeeshop.ca/) used to describe worn books.

Comment: I fully understand your points. Page can be a book page, newspaper page, magazine page, or even webpage (I know the OP doesn't have this in mind). Just looking for an opposite word of a single word without any context doesn't make a good question IMHO. If you are talking about 1,000-year old Bible for example, **well-preserved** could be an ideal opposite word.

Comment: @Rathony - I never said this was a great question. I agree it could be improved. That said, I don't think it's unanswerable in its current state. In fact, it brings up an interesting point, in that the website's listed antonyms for _torn_ aren't applicable to something that's easily torn, such as the page of a book or newspaper. That is worth addressing in and of itself, and I don't see a need to press for any more context than that.

Comment: I tried to discuss this issue in the chat room, but let me put my summary here. 1. The question is off-topic as it is. Especially when an experienced user asks that type of question, I think the user should be guided to write it with context. 2. The question only has one clue which is an opposite to be used predicatively. In that sense, the word "intact" doesn't seem right. As you well know, if any dictionary has all the ant/synonyms that could fit all the context, EL&U and ELL's questions would be halved. 3. There could be no such words because "not torn" is broadly used for that purpose.

Comment: @Rathony - You're not saying anything here that can't be gleaned from your other comments. You'd like to see this question get more context. You think it's hard to answer as is. You think _not torn_ is perhaps the best option. These are all defensible positions, but let's not [belabor the point](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/does-elu-have-it-worse-than-other-sites#comment30206_7535).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by opposite. If you mean a page that was torn and is now not torn, those given words work.

If you mean a page that has never been torn, a word like **whole** works.